# Creating a scope on an ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a ActiveRecord model called Panda with a column called variant, which can consist of values like ‘bam-abc’, ‘bam-123’, ‘boo-abc’ and ‘boo-123’  I want to create a scope which selects all records where the variant starts with ‘boo’.

In the console, I can select those records (starting with ‘boo') with the following:

```
Panda.select{|p| p.variant.starts_with? 'boo'}
```

Is there a way to turn that into a scope on the Panda class?  I need to be able to do a 'to_sql' on the scope for my RSpec tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) that sends a LIKE into the database, something like:

```
scope :boos, -> { where('pandas.variants like ?', 'boo%') }
```

or equivalently, use a class method:

```
def self.boos
  where('pandas.variants like ?', 'boo%')
end
```

Then you can say things like:

```
Panda.boos.where(...)
Panda.where(...).boos
Panda.boos.where(...).to_sql
Panda.where(...).boos.to_sql
```

You only need to use the `pandas` prefix on the column name if you think you'll be doing JOINs with other tables that might leave the `variant` name ambiguous. If you'll never be doing JOINs or you'll only ever have one `variant` column in your database then you could use one of:

```
scope :boos, -> { where('variants like ?', 'boo%') }

def self.boos
  where('variants like ?', 'boo%')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, very comprehensive!

Answer (score 0):

Add the line below to the Panda class

```
scope :boo, -> { where('variant LIKE ?', 'boo%') }
```

You can then use `Panda.boo` to get all the records with variant starting with boo. `Panda.boo.to_sql` will give you the sql